# Saving a .zip file from cURL GET request in python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, zip

I am trying to implement Amplitude's export API in a Python script. I have been using the requests library, but I cannot figure out how to designate a file name to save the response from the call to. This API requires that a .zip file to save as be specified (>> yourfilename.zip) because that is the format that the response comes back as. Here is the example cURL call from the API's website that I am trying to translate into Python:

`curl -u API_Key:Secret_Key 'https://amplitude.com/api/2/export?start=start_date&end=end_date' >> yourfilename.zip`

When I call this in my terminal, it works perfectly and saves the 'yourfilename.zip' to my local. However, the following Python code does not work :

```
    import requests 

    params = (
        ('start', START_DATE),
        ('end', END_DATE),
    )

    auth = (
        ('API_Key', API_KEY),
        ('Secret_Key', SECRET_KEY),
    )
    response = requests.get('https://amplitude.com/api/2/export', params=params, auth=auth, stream=True)
```

the requests.get() call fails to execute with a 403 response because I do not know how to specify a .zip file to save as like the example cURL call on the API's website desires. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `403 forbidden` it appears that you did not receive the response in the first place. If you did you can simply write `r.contents` to a file.zip ```if r.status_code is 200:
with open(f'file.zip', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(response.content)```

Answer (score 1):

```py
    import requests
    import json
    import sys, io
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    import gzip

    auth_data = {'key': 'somekey', 'secret': 'somesecretkey'}
    params = (('start', '20200106T00'), ('end', '20200106T23'),)

    rd = requests.get('https://amplitude.com/api/2/export',
                     params=params,
                     auth=(auth_data['key'], auth_data['secret']),
                     stream=True)

    if rd.status_code == 200:
        zf = ZipFile(io.BytesIO(rd.content), 'r')
    else:
        sys.exit()

    event_list = []
    for gz_file in zf.filelist:
        gz_bdata = zf.read(gz_file.filename)
        js_rows =  gzip.decompress(gz_bdata)
        js_rows = js_rows.decode('utf8')
        for s in js_rows.split('\n'):
            if s:
                event_list.append(json.loads(s))
```